# Prove that if $a|c, b|c, b|a$, then $\frac{a}{b}|c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

I'm working through a proof and in the proof I need to understand a step.

If the following would be true, I would understand the step: if $a|c, b|c, b|a$, then $\frac{a}{b}|c$

Can someone verify whether my attempt is correct?

**Attempt:** By definition, there are integers $x,y,z$ such that:

$ax = c, by = c, bz = a$

Hence, $bzx = c = by \Rightarrow xz = y$

We also have (from the last equation)

$$z = \frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Thus, $$x\frac{a}{b}=y \Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}(xb) = yb = c \Rightarrow \frac{a}{b} |c \quad \triangle$$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is your statement correct?

Comment: You had the proof in the third line of your attempt. $bxz = c$ so $z\mid c$ and $z = a/b$.

Comment: Don't know. If the proof is, then the statement too.

Comment: @Math_QED I gather you are assuming $b\ne 0$ (since you talk about $\frac ab$). This is kind of important because otherwise $bxz=by$ does not imply $xz=y$. (While, even without said hypothesis, it would still be true that, for any three integers $b\mid a\mid c$, any integer $k$ such that $a=kb$ divides $c$).

Comment: Yes, in the context where I need the statement $b \neq 0$

Comment: $c/(a/b) = b(c/a)\in\Bbb Z \,$ by $\, b,\,c/a\in\Bbb Z\ \ $

Comment: It is not even nesscary to say b|c since we already have a|c and b|a. Thus ax = c and by = a. Hence byx = c. We can conclude that b|c

Comment: $b|a \implies b \ne 0$ as $0 \not \mid a$ for any $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the condition $b|c$ is not needed, and for the solution, think about prime factorizations of $a,b$ and $c$, it's very trivial to understand why $a/b$ would divide $c$.

$a/b$ is an integer, and $a/(a/b)=b$ , hence it divides $a$ and $a$ divides $c$, hence it divides $c$.

Answer (score 0):

$a|c$ means $aw = c$ for some integer $w$.

$b|c$ means $bv = c$ for some integer $v$

and $b|a$ means $bu = a$ for some integer $u$.

So we which to show that $\frac ab$ (which equals $u$) divides $c$.

$c = aw = buw = u(bw) = \frac ab*(bw)$ so $\frac 1b|c$.

We can forget variables, $u,v,w$ and just state:  $c = a * \frac ca = \frac ab*b*\frac ca$ and as $b|a$ and $a|c$ we know $\frac ab$ and $\frac ca$ are integers.  So $\frac ab|c$.